Cannot resolve method 'getStatus' in 'ResponseStatusException' in Spring Boot 3
I have this Spring Boot 2.x.x code which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3:
if (ex instanceof ResponseStatusException) {
      return  ((ResponseStatusException) ex).getStatus().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

I tried this:
return  ((ResponseStatusException) ex).getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.java
Is this the proper way just changing getStatus to getStatusCode?

Yes,getStatusCode() is the correct substitution.
You can see the change here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/28ac0d3883e0c683fb995dffc0af7c8a82f3c3d0#diff-63747db89909f3050833efe38439d4f5ba79d66baf952d1c16d6651652719d0f
Also, note that access to getReasonPhrase() is obfuscated with this change, so if you need it, you need to cast or utilize some of the static methods introduced.
